# How do I take data from multiple node-request bodies and pass into an EJS file

Tags: javascript, node.js, ejs, node-request

I am creating a website which uses an api to dispaly football (soccer) scores, fixtures etc. I have tried to create a global variable to save the request data to and then pass into ejs however this doesn't seem to work.

```
router.get('/stats', (req, res) => {


request(options, function (error, response, body) {
    if (error) throw new Error(error);

  top_scorer_data = JSON.parse(body)

});


request(options2, function (error, response, body) {
    if (error) throw new Error(error);

  top_assists_data = JSON.parse(body)

});


request(options3, function (error, response, body) {
    if (error) throw new Error(error);

  top_red_cards_data = JSON.parse(body)  

});


request(options4, function (error, response, body) {
    if (error) throw new Error(error);

  top_yellow_cards_data = JSON.parse(body)

});

res.render('bundesliga/stats', {})

})
```

Answer (score 0):

You should follow DRY principle and move `request` to a service or a helper function.
You shouldn't use global variables, use promises instead, and wait for all requests to finish.

So, you should promisify request method (you should really migrate to `axios` or `node-fetch`, because `request` is deprecated)

and then use `Promise.all` to make all the requests with each option, and then gather results into variables, which you then pass to the `.render` method.

Try this:

```
router.get('/stats', async(req, res) => {

    function getData(options) {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            request(options, function(error, response, body) {
                if (error) reject(error);
                resolve(JSON.parse(body));
            });
        });
    }



    const [top_scorer_data, top_assists_data, top_red_cards_data, top_yellow_cards_data] = await Promise.all([
        getData(options),
        getData(options2),
        getData(options3),
        getData(options4)
    ]).catch(err => {
        console.log('err', err);
    });

    res.render('bundesliga/stats', {
        top_scorer_data,
        top_assists_data,
        top_red_cards_data,
        top_yellow_cards_data
    });

});
```

Comment: When using the code suggested by traynor I'm returned 'undefined' data from the getData funtion. Even whilst using the await keyword leading me to believe that the aysynchoronous nature shouldn't be an issue.

Comment: @rk9 it's hard to say what the problem is without details.. did you try logging `top_scorer_data` and other data, is that undefined? are you sure `request `is returning the data? try returning manually some dummy data from the `getData`, instead of request, and then log promise.all variables. if that works, it means there is a problem with request..